# How to assign location based orders to specific users on WordPress (WooCommerce)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

I have a WooCommerce store which is connected to ASP.NET MVC via Woo API. All the order processing is done via the ASP.NET site and I am using Woo for managing subscription only.

There are about a few hundred subscriptions/orders and I was thinking if there is a way to group orders (all other data as well) on the basis of Address/City/Community etc.

I have tried a few plugins including Advanced Custom Fields plugin for assigning companies to each user (an additional field such as company name) and User Groups plugin for adding groups that are assigned to users (group users based on companies) which gets me as far as assigning Companies to a user and then on Woo Orders page I could select a Company to filter all order related to that company.

But what I really need is a way to do this on user login, so when an admin user A logs in, they will only see orders/subscriptions/customers in their respective group A only. Can this be done via a plugin or do I need to add some sort of customization which gets logged in Admin's group and then use that value to fetch data for that group only? Please advise any possible option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my requirements, the goal is to show orders based on a specific location (that are placed for services related to a specific area such as location-A). Now, I need an Admin User-A to view orders/subscriptions of customers belong to location-A. I do want to prevent Admin User-A to view orders/subscriptions that are placed by customers belong to Location-B. Same is the case for Admin User-B and so on.

So I added the following customization to my active theme's functions.php and I got resolved my problem.

```
function company_filter_orders($query) {
global $post_type;
$customers = array();
if($post_type === 'shop_order' || $post_type === 'shop_subscription')
{
    $curr_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    // the value is 0 if the user isn't logged-in
    if ( $curr_user_id != 0 ) {
        // we know now the user is logged-in, so we can use his/her ID to get the user meta
        $um_value = get_user_meta( $curr_user_id, 'company', true );
        // now we check if the value is correct
        if ( ! empty( $um_value ) ){
            // now we get all the users whose company matches meta_value

            $members = get_users(array(
                    'meta_key' => 'company', 
                    'meta_value' => $um_value,
                )
            );
            //build an array of company users/customers only
            foreach( $members as $usr ) {
                $customers[] = $usr->ID;
            }
        }
    }

    if(count($customers) > 0)
    {   //set meta query to match customer id with above setup array of customers
        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(        
            array(
                  'key' => '_customer_user',
                  'value' => $customers, //pass array of customers to fetch orders/subscriptions for those customers only
                  'compare' => 'IN',
                  'type' => 'numeric'
            )
        ));
    }
}

return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'company_filter_orders');
```

I hope this will help someone having the same problem in WordPress woocommerce.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add three fields to user table  that are going to contain address, city, community. Or if it is difficult to you use tags with bigger areas.

Since the order is connected with the customer with the Id of customer, you can create a view in the database that is going to present the orders plus the location info,to create a php file template with name page-myorders.php and a page with title myorders and then can retrieve the info that you ask. This page is going to query the database using the view. If you use tags you need to pass as parameter the tag to wp_query:

Display posts that do not have any of the two tag ids 37 and 47:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag__not_in' => array( 37, 47 ) ) );
```

see https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Happy coding

Comment: How to i add the page template you suggested to this page ..... wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order
It is the page when as an administrator in WP, user clicks on WooCommerce main menu item.

Comment: The page is going to be at front end, and you must call it from menu